# Macro has stopped working

Tags: vba, excel

My wife has a spread sheet at work that has stopped working.  You input the data into one tab on a nice easy to use sheet, then press a button and the data is transferred to a table on another sheet.  the input tab is called "NCR Report" and the table tab is called "PM2" below is the macro.  Any idea why it has stopped working?

```
Sub Button111_Click()
Dim a As Date
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Filled As Boolean
Dim ParamOut As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Reels As String


MsgBox ("Wait...")



'Identify 1st empty row
Counter = 3
While Filled = False
    Counter = Counter + 1
    a = Worksheets("PM 2").Cells(Counter, 1).Value
    If a = 0 Then
        Filled = True
        Else: Filled = False
    End If

Wend

'Shift
 Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(2, 7).Value

'Production date
 Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 1).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(3, 7).Value

 'Article number
 Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 4).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(4, 7).Value

 'Total weight
  Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 5).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(16, 8).Value

'Parameter out, build the string
ParamOut = ""
For i = 21 To 24
    If Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 2).Text <> "" Then

        ParamOut = ParamOut & " " & Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 2).Text & " " & Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 5).Text & " " & Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 9).Text & " " & Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 10).Text
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 6).Value = ParamOut

'Adjustements
 Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 7).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(29, 2).Value

'Reel number
Reels = ""
Reels = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(10, 2).Text


    For i = 11 To 15
     If Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
          Else: Reels = Reels & " / " & Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(i, 2).Text
        End If
    Next i

Worksheets("PM2").Cells(Counter, 3).Value = Reels

MsgBox ("NCR has been successfully added to the spreadsheet." & vbCrLf & "Don't forget to save this file before quitting and also to block the reels on PLAIN.")


End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to add the error message "Run-time error '9':  Script out of range

Comment: No idea. On which line does this script crash?

Comment: it seems to be on hte a = Worksheet ("PM2").Cells(Counter, 1).Value

Comment: You say it's stopped working. What has been changed from when it was working to now?

Comment: Is it possible to see what a typical 'NCR Report' tab looks like? I'm plugging random numbers onto the cell references and it's copying them without issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking.  I got hold of an older version which was working and replicated the data into that to see why it broke.  Turns out someone had manually put some data in leaving column A blank (Date) this was coursing the error.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You've got inconsistent references to the sheet name.
In one case its:

> a = Worksheets("**PM 2**").Cells(Counter, 1).Value

And later its:

> Worksheets("**PM2**").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = Worksheets("NCR Report").Cells(2, 7).Value

The code needs to match the actual name of the worksheet, either with or without the space

Comment: Thanks for that.  Got rid of the space but know get a run time 13 error